# Python/Django Extract and append only new links

Tags: python, django

I am putting together a project using Python 2.7 Django 1.5 on Windows 7.
I have the following view:

views.py:

```
def foo():
    site = "http://www.foo.com/portal/jobs"
    hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
    jobpass = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(jobpass)
    for tag in soup.find_all('a', href = True):
        tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin('http://www.businessghana.com/portal/',  tag['href'])
    return map(str, soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile('.getJobInfo')))

def example():
    site = "http://example.com"
    hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
    jobpass = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(jobpass)
    return map(str, soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile('.display-job')))

 foo_links = foo()
 example_links = example()

def all_links():
    return (foo_links + example_links)

def display_links(request):
    name = all_links()
    paginator = Paginator(name, 25)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        name = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        name = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        name = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('jobs.html', {'name' : name})
```

my template looks like this:

```
<ol>
{% for link in name %}
  <li> {{ link|safe }}</li>
{% endfor %}
 </ol>
 <div class="pagination">
<span class= "step-links">
    {% if name.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ names.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class = "current">
        Page {{ name.number }} of {{ name.paginator.num_pages}}.
    </span>

    {% if name.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ name.next_page_number}}">next</a>
    {% endif %}
</span>
 </div>
```

Right now as my code stands, anytime I run it, it scraps all the links on the frontpage of the sites selected and presents them paginated **all afresh**.
However, 
I don't think its a good idea for the script to read/write all the links that had previously extracted links all over again and therefore would like to check for and append only new links. I would like to save the previously scraped links so that over the course of say, a week, all the links that have appeared on the frontpage of these sites will be available on my site as older pages.

It's my first programming project and don't know how to incorporate this logic into my code.

UPDATE:

My model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class jobLinks(models.Model):
    links = models.URLField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date retrieved')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.links
```

Any help/pointers/references will be greatly appreciated.

regards,
Max

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend building URL table and having a date field in the table to use for sorting by so your most recent URL's are listed first as you described that you are trying to do with pagination.  Your URL table might look like so:

```
models.py:

class URL_Table(models.Model):
  date = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True)
  url = models.URLField()
```

You can sort by date descending like so and link this to your views in `views.py`:

```
urls = URL_Table.objects.order_by('-date')
```

You can then reference this table to see if the URL exists already.  If it a new URL then save it to the table.

You could also override `get()` in your `views.py` view function to do something when the page loads, or build a `custom model method` that only does some kind of URL maintenance if the URL's are more than one week old using `django.utils.timezone` or `datetime.datetime` in python

**UPDATE:**

If you want to check for links that are already saved to your table, and only save the new ones, then call all of your links and check vs. your new links.  You can choose to only show links created in the last week using a timedelta.  So I would recommend using two functions here.

Use this function to check for new links, and only save the new ones:

```
def save_new_links(all_links):
  current_links = joblink.objects.all()
  for i in all_links:
    if i not in current_links:
      joblink.objects.create(url=i)
```

Then call all links in the last week using timedelta

```
def this_weeks_links(all_links):
  return joblinks.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.timedelta(days=-7))
```

Then insert these functions into your view to **#1** only save the new links, and **#2** only display on your first page links saved in the last week.

Good luck!

Comment: I've currently created a model, which I've updated in the question above. I need to now save the data generated by the `display_links(request)` view. I have searched and searched but all I find is saving data from forms. Can you please assist me on that? thanks

Comment: You need to save the data from `display_links(request)` as a model instance.  So if you model is called `Site` then save it as `site = Site.objects.create(name=name, site=site)` those are example names for the fields, but the point is just to save the info as a model instance in order to save it to the database. Or use the existing Site model instance, update it, and then use the method `.save()` to save the changes you made. hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried but I'm not getting it. I've read everthing on [Django model documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#topics-db-models) as well as other stuff but still didn't get to incorporate that logic in my code. Can you please_give me the fish_ so that I can move on to completing other parts of my tiny project. I've currently stalled and would be happy if you could modify your main answer to reflect how my views.py is suppose to look like to make this works for me. thanks in advance

Comment: ok, read my update. that should help. let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: sorry to worry you again. but when I added the two functions to my views, everything went away :(. No links were showing anymore. But I edited the  second function to return 'jobs.links.object.all' and everything came back but still the database was empty..

Comment: If everything came back with "jobs.links.objects.all" then your database can't be empty.  Can you add your current view code, so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: here's the link to a pastebin of my entire view: http://pastebin.com/0SaiRVTU .. Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Please re-read my updated code.  You didn't copy all of the code over to your Pastebin.com page.  Also, you need to import datetime in order to use that function and also call the functions from inside your main display view.